# Favicon still in Beta

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

It looks like the [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) is still showing the Beta icon. Can this be fixed, please (for Main and Meta)?

Comment: I am still having this problem (main site only).

Comment: @Beofett: yeah, I don't get it. It seems to be working OK now, but different users seem to see it working or not at different times. Did you Ctrl-F5?

Comment: LOL no, but when I went to go back to the main site to try Ctrl-F5, the Favicon had fixed itself.

Comment: @Beofett: it's updated for me, but not in my bookmark history. Probably a browser issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the new favicon.  Maybe a hard cache clear is necessary?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe that is it. Now I get the new Favicon in meta, but not yet main. Looks like it is a local setting (even though I tried different browsers). Thanks!

Comment: I still show the old favicon in Chrome for the main site. The hard refresh fixed the meta favicon.

Comment: @Beofett: same here. I think it is not fixed for the main site.

Comment: And now it looks fine on both main and meta!

Comment: Mine still shows the beta on the main site.

Comment: @Beofett So does mine, but only in Chrome, so it's definitely a browser cache issue.