# Sci-fi blog shows the wrong favicon

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, blog

If you go to the sci-fi blog it still shows the favicon from the beta instead of the new one.

Comment: As Beofett notes, if you're seeing this it's because your browser hasn't woken up to the new icon yet - the server *is* willing to send it. Try Ctrl+F5, or just wait.

Comment: @Shog9 Nope, still not showing up with `wget --no-cache`.

Answer (score 4):

The correct Favicon shows for me, and I was one of the [last people to see the correct one for the regular site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/favicon-still-in-beta).

It is most likely a caching issue similar to the one that I, and several other users, experienced.  It seems that some browsers (in my case, Chrome) have significant delays in updated Favicons, and instead rely on cached data in some way that is not quite clear.

Hard refreshes of the browser sometimes help, but sometimes it appears that simply waiting a few days will be required.

Answer (score 2):

Right now I see no favicon at all: `/favicon.ico` exists but is empty.

```
$ wget -nv --no-cache -O- http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/favicon.ico | wc -c
2011-12-22 20:53:45 URL:http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/favicon.ico [0] -> "-" [1]
0
```

Comment: The path that *should* be requested is: http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/stackexchange/sites/scifi/images/favicon.ico - and that one works just fine.

Comment: Many clients will look for /favicon.ico, for example RSS readers, since they can't know about the alternate location unless they first retrieve the meta tag in the HTML. This leads to many unneeded 404's. For this reason it's better to leave it in the root.

Answer (score 0):

It's now showing correctly for me